# Permitted param with multiple types

Tags: ruby-on-rails

permitted params is defined as follows

```
params.permit(
          feature_settings: %i[
            name
            enabled: %i[
              enabled
            ]
          ])
```

**enabled** param in feature_settings can be **boolean value or an object**

The output for params is as follows

```
"feature_settings"=>[{"name"=>"settings 1", "enabled"=>{"enabled"=>false}}, {"name"=>"settings 2", "enabled"=>true}]
```

The output for permitted_params[:feature_settings] is as follows

```
    permitted_params[:feature_settings]
=> [<ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"settings 1"} permitted: true>,
 <ActionController::Parameters {"name"=>"settings 2", "enabled"=>true} permitted: true>,
```

Settings 1 is not returning the **enabled** hash. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: if you can, fix your api request schema. this kind of polymorphism is probably not necessary. why cant you just always use the boolean OR the object version?

Comment: agree with @MarianTheisen else you need to mention `enabled` again while permitting, one for key and other for accepting nested attributes. like `params.permit(feature_settings: [:name, :enabled, enabled: [:enabled]])`